# django model-translation, can't filter on multilingual

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-modeltranslation

I'm trying to implement multi-language on my site using django-modeltranslation, but I can't filter product by category when switched to other languages, I'm using Python 3.10.6, Django 4.2, django-modeltranslation 0.18.9 my code:

model.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def CourseListView(request):
    qs = Course.objects.all()

    categories = Category.objects.all()

    category = request.GET.get('category')

    if is_valid_queryparam(category) and category != 'All categories':
        qs = qs.filter(categories__name=category)
        qs = qs.filter(Q(categories__name_en='category') | 
            Q(categories__name_fr='category'))
    context = {
        'queryset': qs,
        'categories': categories,
    }
```

urls.py

```
path('', CourseListView, name='course-list'),
```

course_list.htnl

```
<form method="GET" action=".">
    <select  onchange="this.form.submit()" id="category" name="category">
        <option selected>{% translate "All categories" %}</option>
        {% for cat in categories  %}
        <option value="{{ cat }}">{{ cat }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
```

I have tried to use this code it doesn't work,

```
if is_valid_queryparam(category) and category != 'All categories':
    qs = qs.filter(Q(categories__name_en='category') | 
    Q(categories__name_fr='category'))
```

However this one do work but on default language only:

```
if is_valid_queryparam(category) and category != 'All categories':
    qs = qs.filter(categories__name=category)
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `Q(categories__name_en=category)`?

Comment: Thanks, that works but when language is switched to fr(french) for example it fails to filter

Comment: you should remove the quotes from `'category'`, so `category`, otherwise you take `category` as a string literal, not as the value of a variable named `category`.

Comment: doesn't work  qs = qs.filter(Q(categories__name_en=category) | Q(categories__name_fr=category))